# Subtracting values based on a index column and using a condition in the same column in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I've a lot of material on Stack about this, but i'm still not able to reproduce it.

Sample data set.

| Asset | Value | Index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 1 |
| B | 15 | 1 |
| C | 20 | 1 |
| A | 11 | 2 |
| B | 17 | 2 |
| C | 24 | 2 |
| A | 18 | 3 |
| B | 25 | 3 |
| C | 30 | 3 |

What i want to do is, subtract the Asset values individually based on the index column.

Ex:

Asset A [1] -> 10
Asset A [2] -> 11

11 - 10 = 1

So the table would be like this.

| Asset | Value | Index | Diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 1 | 0 |
| B | 15 | 1 | 0 |
| C | 20 | 1 | 0 |
| A | 11 | 2 | 1 |
| B | 17 | 2 | 2 |
| C | 24 | 2 | 4 |
| A | 18 | 3 | 7 |
| B | 25 | 3 | 8 |
| C | 30 | 3 | 6 |

This need's to be done using DAX.

Can you guys help me ?

Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I just did this and it worked.

```
Diff = 

var Assets = 'Table'[Asset]
var Ind = 'Table'[Index] - 1

Return

IF(Ind = -1, 0, 'Table'[Value] - CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Value]),FILTER('Table','Table'[Asset] = Assets && 'Table'[Index] = Ind)))
```